# Foundry - is number/time of unclaimed limited?

Tags: warframe

*Since there is a limitation of our inventory when it comes to warframes and weapons for example I was wondering - since I'm crafting most things ASAP as I get their blueprints and the materials...*

Is there a limit of how many items **ready to claim** I can have in foundry
+ do they stay there forever until I claim them or they can dissappear one day?

I've read that if item dissappears from foundry I can send a ticket, but I'm not very good with my memory so I would probably notice I'm missing an item but wouldn't remember which one. Does this happen often or does it even happen anymore now?

Comment: Damn you @Frank ! I want that new tag `crafting` :D

Comment: It's unneccessary, I'm afraid.  The only tags we really create are game tags; the rest need a much higher bar, and crafting is too broad to really be useful.  We'd never have experts in it.

Comment: Oh well.. okay.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment I have managed to craft all frames and available prime frames (besides Nezha), as well as about half the weapons (primes included), and about 80% of all my stuff is still in the foundry.

Safe to say that if there was a limit, I would've reached it long ago.

**No**, there is no limit of how much stuff you have in your foundry that is unclaimed.

Edit: Though you aren't allowed to have multiple instances of the same items in the foundry (i.e. you can't craft a new forma while having a finished forma unclaimed).

Comment: How long do u play the game if I may ask?

Comment: Several months. Several very active months...

Comment: In contrast, I've only used formas on two weapons, and those would be my Redeemer and Latron Prime. Rest is for either foundry BPs, weapon fuse BPs, and some rooms in the dojo. A couple of hours a week gives you a nice supply of formas. T4 keys from excavations, trade those for some T3 at a fair ratio, and that should get you most high-end prime parts in a reasonable time. Besides, 20-30k cash per finite mission is more than plenty. Don't think I've ever had more than 600k creds at this point.

Comment: Done, was just waiting if anyone has other experience, since it's less likely to get more answers in question with accepted answer.

Comment: @Ms.Nobody Fair point.

Comment: There is a limit as far as one type of item waiting.  In other words, once you have a set of dual zorens waiting and completed, you may not craft another (which you would need to do to build other weapons from).  Also you cannot use a weapon waiting to be claimed to build another weapon.

Comment: @SuspendedUser That's actually a good point to bring up. Thanks.